# React Table - useRowSelect change select all default behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am using the selection hook in my react table and I can't find a way to override the select all checkbox behavior.
When the select all checkbox is checked if you uncheck a specific row in the table it turns the `isAllRowsSelected` to false.

I want it to change only if the header checkbox is clicked, because I want to be able to have a state that says "all results, except the unmarked ones".

I am using server side pagination so I can't rely only on the `selectedRowIds` array.
This is the implementation of `useRowSelect` I used : [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/row-selection)

Comment: How did you solve this, I have the exact same need?

Comment: @jamesemanon i implemented my own hook based on useRowSelect, then you can implement your own logic in the reducer function

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line, it trigers on component mount.

```
React.useEffect(()=> {toggleAllRowsSelected()},[])
```

All code like this: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-cherry-c6hsz)